# Проблемы с Вorland C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, borland

Что делать с Borland, если при компиляции он выдает ошибку в правильно написанном коде в базовой части любой программы?

**Дополнено.**

> `error ../../../Conversi.cpp 6: Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'`
> `error ../../../Conversi.cpp 7: Unable to open include file 'iostream.h'`
> `error ../../../Conversi.cpp 12: Undefined symbol 'cout'`

Comment: @стаsik Приведите код ваше программы и текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Вы были правы: Options/Directores. И еще простите за нубство, но что делать если:

Warning ..\..\Docume~1\Admin\0016~1\C\PROJEKT\CONVERSI.CPP 31: Parameter 'nNumberofArgs' is never used.
Warning ..\..\Docume~1\Admin\0016~1\C\PROJEKT\CONVERSI.CPP 31: Parameter 'pszArgs' is never used.
C++ я только начал осваивать. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно прописать в настройках среды, где лежат заголовочные файлы. Это Options/Directories или что-нибудь подобное, в зависимости от той версии, которую вы используете.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте другие компиляторы. Если и там выдает ошибку, значит, её надо найти.

Answer (score 0):

**Учитесь читать ошибки %)**
И выложите часть кода, иначе это будет не ответ, а гадание на кофейной гуще.
Могу предположить:

- Нет инклудов

:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
```

- В Options>Directories не прописан путь к папке include.
- С чего вы взяли, что код правильный? Если он скопирован или перепечатан с книги - это не означается его правильность.
- "Undefined symbol 'cout'" - это означает, что символ не объявлен. Или же объявлен, но вы ошиблись в его использовании, так как я подозреваю - это переменная "count".

Comment: 4. Это означает ровно то, что означает. Программист использовал наименование `cout`, чтобы сделать вывод на экран. Раз iostream не подключен, этот символ не определен. Как следствие - кластеры ошибок :-)